# Which Ubuntu package to install to get libssl.so.3 and libcrypto.so.3 libraries?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, openssl

I am trying to get AWS localproxy to run on Ubuntu, which requires `libssl.so.3` and `libcrypto.so.3` to be available on the system. I was expecting to have `libssl.so.3` and `libcrypto.so.3` be available when `libssl-dev package` is installed on Ubuntu. However that is not the case. I see however the packages `libssl3.so`, `libssl.so`, and `libcrypto.so` in `/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu` directory.

Comment: have you installed openssl? `sudo apt install openssl` more info here if you need a legacy version: https://learnubuntu.com/install-openssl/

Comment: OP: what version of Ubuntu, and what _exact_ libssl package? libssl3 on jammy up should provide lib{crypto,ssl}.so.3 @FrankThomas+ libssl3.so is not specifically SSLv3, it is part of major version 3 of _Mozilla Network Security Services_ developed for Firefox and Thunderbird but used by quite a few other things, see e.g. https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/amd64/libnss3/filelist